# Why should I check IsCancellationRequested before calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

I often see the following code which is the first view looks good since one is used to check a precondition before doing something else.

But when one reads the name of the method it feels like the preceding if statement already is included in the method itself. So is there any reason to write the code like it is in this example or could one just skip the if-statement and run `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` directly.

Of course its a different thing if one need to cleanup before exiting then I fully understand the use of the if-statement.

```
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't, if you check the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=net-5.0#remarks), since it's the equivalent of `if(A) { if(A) {`.

Comment: That is pointless - just call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` directly

Comment: The other commenters are correct, also take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationToken.cs#L359-L363) (although it is .NET Core) and see that it does exactly what you're expecting it to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: there is no reason to check both.

`cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` and `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` are different approaches to achieve the same goal.

Checking `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is a so-called "soft" way of cancelling a task.

Setting `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is often considered to be the recommended option.

You can find more information on proper task cancellation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/) and [here](https://johnthiriet.com/cancel-asynchronous-operation-in-csharp/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs.html#d2864d73804288fc) of the [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) method:

```
public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
{
    if (IsCancellationRequested) 
        ThrowOperationCanceledException();
}
```

It should be pretty obvious that checking the [`IsCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested) property before calling this method serves no purpose, other than converting a tiny amount of electricity to heat.